# How to prevent click while scrolling in ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-viewpager2

How can I prevent calling "onClick" while scrolling in **ViewPager2**?
Please pay attention that I ask about ViewPager2.
When I scroll the view pager, an item is clicked.

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

PageViewAdapter

```
class PageViewAdapter(
    private val context: Context,
    private val list: ArrayList<Video>,
    private val lifecycle: Lifecycle
) :
    RecyclerView.Adapter<PageViewAdapter.MyViewHolder>() {

           override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): MyViewHolder {
        val view =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.fragment_video, parent, false)
        return MyViewHolder(view).apply {
            playerView.setOnClickListener {
                playOrResume()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: MyViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val mediaSource = buildMediaSource(list[position].uri)
        holder.player.prepare(mediaSource)

    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return list.size
    }

    inner class MyViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val playerView: PlayerView = itemView.player_view
        val player: SimpleExoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(
            context,
            DefaultRenderersFactory(context),
            DefaultTrackSelector(),
            DefaultLoadControl()
        )    
        fun playOrResume() {
            player.playWhenReady = !player.playWhenReady
        }


    }
}
```

Here you can watch the video of the actions:
https://vimeo.com/340232497

Comment: I cant view that video, it needs permission

Comment: @Erik, thanks. Replaced the link.

Comment: I get HTTP ERROR 500, use Drive to host your vid, Google drive it´s good

Comment: @Erik please check it now

Comment: ok so it start playing when you only want to scroll

Answer (score 1):

Only make the recyclerView react to click events when it is not scrolling:

```
if (recyclerView.scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
    playOrResume()
}
```

**Update**

Maybe something like this will work:

```
private static int mScrollState;

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView,int dx, int dy) {
        super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        scrollState = recyclerView.scrollState;
    }
    // or use this method for finer control
    @Override
    public void onScrollStateChanged(RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
        switch (newState) {
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE:
               System.out.println("The RecyclerView is not scrolling");
               break;
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING:
                System.out.println("Scrolling now");
                break;
            case RecyclerView.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING:
                System.out.println("Scroll Settling");
                break;
     }

}

});
```

Use the `mScrollState` inside the `ClickListener` to check state

**Update**

So `onCLick` is called before the `onScrollStateChanged`, use this `Handler` in the `onCLick` and it will halt for 200 and that will enable `onScrollStateChanged` to activate

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    if (recyclerView.scrollState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {
        playOrResume()
    }
  }
}, 200);
```

Comment: I hade to look this up myself, maybe it´s not correct but you can try

Comment: But I don't have the field scrollState" in the adapter. As I see, Maybe I need to move my clickListener to activity and get the state from there.

Comment: But I use ViewPager2 instead of RecyclerView. ViewPager2 doesn't have the method "addOnScrollListener". The class contains a method "setOnScrollChangeListener" and I don't see here state of scrolling.

Comment: ok I see, maybe if you use this [`ViewPager2.getScrollState()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2)

Comment: onCLick is called before method onScrolled and onScrollStateChanged

Comment: Maybe you could place a handler with delay 200 milisec , check my update. This feels like a dirty hack but anyway..

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll want to try the methods in [ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback.html).

```
val pageChangeCallback = object : ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {

  override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
    // New page becomes selected.
  }

  override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {
    // Current page is scrolled.
  }

  override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
    when(state) {
      ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_DRAGGING -> {
        // User begins dragging or a fake drag is started.
      }

      ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE -> {
        // Pager is fully stopped/idle.
      }

      ViewPager2.SCROLL_STATE_SETTLING -> {
        // Pager is automatically settling to the current page.
      }
    }
  }
}

// Register the callback to the pager.
viewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback)


// TODO viewPager2.unregisterOnPageChangeCallback(pageChangeCallback)
```

Comment: onCLick is called before the method onPageScrollStateChanged

Comment: Hmm. Help me understand the uses of `context` and `lifecycle` in PageViewAdapter's constructor.

The context you need in `onCreateViewHolder` can be reached via `parent.context`.

Comment: I've cut some part of my code in this class to not overload the question. You can look at my full class here - https://gist.github.com/56276c865221be2a3f1a57151645c264
I need lifecycle to pause the video when I get onPause()

Comment: Sorry friend. I'm unable to replicate the behavior you're observing. My viewPager callbacks and its items' click listeners behave as expected. I'm curious if the issue might be further along in `MyViewHolder`, `PlayerView`, or `Player.EventListener`.